# Does Android has native accessible localized text?

Tags: android, localization

We are porting an app from iOS to Android, and for some reason the client want us to add an "Exit Form" when the user click the back button, a thing that simple doesn't exit in iOS.

Since we don't the budget for localization, we were wondering if Android has some kind of native generic text we could acces, like "Do you want to Exit this app?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are some [standard text strings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html). However it is not much. They are accessible through the `R.string` class or through `@android:string/`.